# Index Page with data driven pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages, indexing

[image]I am trying to create an index page using a customized index polygon featureclass that I created. Is there a way to do that without using the grid index features tool, which is more for set sized grids, but for a customized polygon set?

Comment: The Grid Index Features tool is for creating a feature class that can be the source of an index layer. Can you include a picture of what you want your index "page" to look like please?

Comment: http://image.slidesharecdn.com/marketresearchondistributionsystemofpepsi-140418151325-phpapp01/95/market-research-on-distribution-system-of-pepsi-project-report-8-638.jpg?cb=1397892364

Comment: There is a picture button that you can use when you [edit] your question to post an image there.  Potential answerers are not always willing to follow links to try and piece a question together.

Comment: just added picture now

Comment: How does that index page relate to the map layouts generated by Data Driven Pages?

Comment: Basically I want a table of contents with my city blocks as the contents and the page number as the page number.

Answer (score 1):

One option to look into if the polygons you have fall in a relatively linear fashion, you could consider using the Strip Map Index Features (Cartography) geoprocessing tool:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000034000000

Comment: I tried using the strip map index features tool and used the selection by location to select out only the ones that contain the index polygon feature, but there was too much overlap of polygons and some of the areas that i needed covered didn't end up getting covered.